# Does a MongoDB collection's document count affect performance?

Tags: mongodb

I'm not sure why I can't find any information on this, but I'd like to find out what performance consequences might exist when a MongoDB collection has a huge number of documents.  I see a lot of answers about the size of documents, but not the document count.

I have a collection of small documents (about 600b each).  There are about 2.3m documents in this collection at the time of this writing.  They're indexed on two fields each.

I'm concerned about the scalability of this collection.  Depending on how many users sign up, this collection could theoretically hit **875+ billion** documents.

Will this impact query performance or the index?

Comment: In general, you have to think in terms of _design_; design of the data. You can design your database based upon your application needs. There are many aspects to it. For example, what is the data, the relationships between various entities, how much data (not theory, but in real), what resources are available, what is your application and its functionality, etc.

Comment: 2.3 million documents at 600 bytes each is ~1,3 GB, which is a rather small dataset that would easily fit entirely in memory on  a really old smartphone.  Definitely test performance with enough data to require cache eviction before considering it production ready.

Answer (score 2):

875B documents at 600b each will definitely give you scaling challenges. 2.3M shouldn't be a problem on even modest hardware.

> I see a lot of answers about the size of documents, but not the document count.

I would think about this in terms of the total collection size (which is influenced by the document count) to get an idea of its scalability. Higher collection size means more RAM required to satisfy the indexes. MongoDB tries to keep indexes in RAM, which makes sense because indexes perform much better when they're in RAM.

Not sure whether you meant 600b as in bits or bytes, but that's either 65 TB or 525 TB. Even with an index or two on only one field each, they're going to be large indexes difficult to fit in memory. Actual performance will probably depend entirely on your query patterns, such as whether you keep accessing the same documents (faster, stays in cache) or whether queries are relatively evenly distributed across the documents (slower, needs more memory to perform well).